# (TypeScript) Creating type definition for Parse SDK (Browser and Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, typescript

I'm creating a Typescript type definition for the [Parse Javascript SDK](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/). It's actually complete. The definition would work for the Browse and Cloud Code but not in Node.

**Using Parse with both client side and server side javascript**

**Browse Example:**

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
```

**Node Example:**

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
```

**Psuedue Type Definition**

```
declare module Parse {

    interface FacebookUtils {
        init(options?: any);
    }

    class Object {
        constructor(attributes?: any, options?: any);

    }

    module Cloud {

        interface FunctionResponse {
            success?: (response: HttpResponse) => void;
            error?: (response: HttpResponse) => void;
        }
    }

}

declare module "parse" {
    export = Parse;
}
```

**Using Parse with newly create definition**

```
class GameScore extends Parse.Object {}

var gameScore = new GameScore();
```

Everything would work fine in the **Browse** because the Parse library is globally available.

Now in **Node** everything would work fine if the import were like this:

```
var Parse = require("parse");
```

But the import is actually like this:

```
var Parse = require("parse").Parse;
```

So the **".Parse"** at the end of the import would cause a problem when trying to access **Parse.Object** because there is no accessor for ".Parse" in the definition above.

So what I want to do is have a single definition file that works for both Browser and Node. I thought about using an interface but I don't think that would allow me to do extends or implements when I want to.

**For example:**

```
declare module Parse {

    ...

    interface Parse {
        Object: Object;
    }
}

declare module "parse" {
        export = Parse;
}
```

This wouldn't allow me to extend **Object**, it's just defined as a property in the Parse interface.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Earl, @basarat has beaten me to it with his good answer below.

Comment: How's the progress on this? Has this been open sourced on GitHub anywhere?

Comment: I'm curious about the status of this project as well.

Comment: @damianesteban Have you guys searched tsd because it's up there. Just do a search for "parse".

Comment: @ fatuhoku search tsd.

Comment: Actually yes I found it last night.  Thank you.

Comment: I found your repo at github aswell =)

Comment: What do I need to do to get the tests in https://github.com/ullisenmedia/parse working? I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bit involved :

```
declare module Parse {

    interface FacebookUtils {
        init(options?: any);
    }

    class Object {
        constructor(attributes?: any, options?: any);

    }

    module Cloud {

        interface FunctionResponse {
            success?: (response: HttpResponse) => void;
            error?: (response: HttpResponse) => void;
        }
    }

}

declare module "parse" {
    var captureType: typeof Parse;
    var subType: {
        Parse: typeof captureType;
    }
    export = subType;
}
```

Usage:

```
///<reference path="parse.d.ts"/>

import parse = require('parse');
var Parse = parse.Parse;
```

## Explanation

To refer to the type of a module you need `typeof`. Knowing this, you might want to do the following but can't for obvious reason (which `Parse` is this? ... the global one? or local?):

```
var Parse: { Parse: typeof Parse }
export = Parse;
```

Hence the verbosity of local Types. Don't worry they do not bloat the generated JavaScript in any way.

Comment: Awesome dude!!!! And so much clearer than I thought it would. Pretty darn cool. Thanks man!!!!